# How to create a type that only accepts valid indices of a constant array?

Tags: typescript

I have a constant array, (with non-empty objects if that helps):

```
const X = [{a: 3}, {a: 4}, {b: 6}] as const;
```

and I want to create the type of valid indices for that array `0 | 1 | 2`. I tried `keyof typeof X`, but that gives me the keys of the array type ('length' | 'toString' ...), neither by playing around with conditional types like so:

```
type CheckIndex<C, T> = typeof C[T] extends undefined ? false : true;
```

How could I get the subcollection of `number`s that are valid indices for a constant array?